# How to close a TMultiview from code in Delphi XE8?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, multiview, delphi-xe8

I have a form with a speedbutton linked to a TMultiView component.
On the multiview I have some buttons. When clicking on any of the buttons I want the multiview to close and depending on the clicked button, different functions to be called. I have tried to set the Visible property of my MultiView to false, but the shadow over the form then remains. If I click on the speedbutton again, then menu disappears, and also the shadow, as expected.
Is there a way to solve this?

I'm using Deplhi XE 8.1

Comment: Try MultiView.HideMaster

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Multiview.HideMaster` will close the multi view. Call this whenever/wherever you want the multiview to close.

Comment: Thanks friend! Good solution